# Is there a legal way to play Mario on PS2?

Tags: ps2, mario-series

I have a PS2 and want to play the classic Mario games on it. I know the PS2 is a Sony product and Mario is a Nintendo product, but that doesn't answer my question because I have seen some non-Sony games made for PS2. So, I am wondering if they made a Mario game  for PS2?

When I googled "PS2 Mario" some images came up of a PS2 version of the Mario collection, so I thought the answer was "yes". But then I also came across some forum posts saying this did not exist, so I thought the answer was "no". Then I came across some places where you can buy or download the Mario collection for PS2, but I couldn't tell if it was a legit (authorized, legal) product.

I'm not looking for a hack that someone came up with in their basement; I'm wondering if they actually made a (legal) game for PS2 in which you can play Mario. Thanks!

Comment: No.  Nintendo has not *ever* let their characters appear on any non-Nintendo devices.

Comment: @Frank What about the arcade machines?

Comment: @Someguy112161 those were built and distributed by Nintendo.

Comment: @5pike I suppose that's possible, I just thought that they just made the game itself, not the cabinet.

Comment: @Someguy112161 True, for many they only provided the games, but they also built arcade machines.

Comment: It depends what you mean by legal.

Answer (score 4):

No there is no legit Mario game for any console other than that of Nintendo.
I have no firm proof to link you to but I can say that Mario is wholly owned by Nintendo whereas as the non-Sony games you allude to for the PS2 are made by companies not directly related to any console manufacturer and the likelihood of Nintendo making a game for a console other than their own is akin to pigs flying.

Comment: Technically there was [Hotel Mario](http://www.giantbomb.com/hotel-mario/3030-5841/), but we don't like to talk about that.

Comment: @Cloudymusic Oh god, I was not aware of that. Excuse me while I go bleach my eyes.

Comment: There are a few exceptions, such as [Mario Teaches Typing](http://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Teaches_Typing).

Comment: @Brian Or any of the other Software Toolworks (I think) games like Mario is Missing and Mario's Time Machine, which are also on PC.

Comment: I've edited the answer to only talk about consoles, this still includes the Phillips game but if Nintendo pretends that never happened it is good enough for me.

Answer (score -2):

the reason emulators are legal is because you can legally backup your data and then use it on any system capable of running that software.

most often people will download the rom file of their catridges because the process of dismantling them not only is risky but the equiptment required to do it is difficult to find expensive and not easy for the average user.

there are also various laws on abandoned work products and copyrights expiring which add grey areas as well.

that said it is not difficult to softmod a ps2 provided you have a computer and access to 007 agent under fire....freemcboot or freehdboot are the most beneficial packages for this in my opinion.once installed there is a plethora of homebrew apps available on sksapps including emulators.

you may be able to find coders capable of writing a custom burned disk encoded to play the games as well but this can also be both expensive and difficult to find one willing to go through the excessive work.